# Joomla db->query. What is the difference between quote types when filling query object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

Im working under Joomla 3.x

There are many different solution for building query objects.

More recent documentations seems to prefer this method:

```
$query->select("*")
$query->from($db->nameQuote('#__example_table'))
$query->where($db->nameQuote('id')." = ".$db->quote('999999'));
```

In similar pages there are some exapmles named as "fully quoted":

```
$query = "
  SELECT * 
  FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__example_table')."  
  WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('id')." = ".$db->quote('999999').";
  ";
```

And straight forward method:

```
$query = " SELECT * 
           FROM #__example_table 
           WHERE 'id' = '999999';
          ";
```

What is the difference between this methods?

When, one of them does not work but other methods can be executed successfully?

Comment: Try 'echo $query' to see what the sql looks like. I also suggest you look up sql injection and when to use backticks and single quotes.

Comment: It's better to do `echo $query->dump();` which will give you the formatted generated statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those methods will work as long as you stick to those aspects of SQL that do not differ from driver to driver or do not care about multi-support.

However please note that your three examples are not equivalent in that you are treating 999999 as a string in the first two and as an integer in the last one.

In general if you care at all about multi-database support or if you want to be sure that your queries won't blow up because you accidentally use a reserved word as a field name and didn't quote it correctly, then the first example is the best (possibly modified based on whether you mean 9999999 or `'999999'`).

Here's why

- All names are quotes with the correct type of marks.
- Things will be correctly escaped (unless you say not to).
- All strings are quoted correctly
- It will work on all of the supported databases.
- It is easy to correctly add additional statements when you need to modify that query because JDatabaseQuery puts them together correctly whatever order you put the statements in.

In terms of what the difference between quote types, in SQL drivers there is usually a difference between backticks and single quotes, `$db->quote()` gives you single quotes and `$db->quoteName()` gives you backticks.